# Context and Instance formal definitions

Tags: openthread

I am new to OpenThread, so there may already exist an answer to this question, but could someone point out the definition of "Context" in OpenThread terminology? Is it the same as "Instance"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may know what it means - in the event that you may need to supplement the functionality of, say, a callback function, the Context can be a pointer to help with that. There might not be a need, but it's there in case you do. I believe that is the most generic way of putting it, but someone else might provide a better (or correct) answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenThread, Context and Instance are separate concepts.  Instance is used to contain state about the Thread networking protocol.  Context is used to support [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation).  In general, the Context is completely opaque to the callee and only for the benefit of the callback handler.